# unrecognizable code in scala Predef object

Tags: scala

Can someone please explain the following code in Predef object? Thanks.

```
scala.`package`     // to force scala package object to be seen.
scala.collection.immutable.List // to force Nil, :: to be seen.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

([Link](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L90)). I can only guess. When you use a singleton object as expression, this has the same effect as forcing the evaluation of a `lazy val`, in other words it will run the object's body if it wasn't yet initialised.

For example:

```
object Foo {
  println("Foo is launching rockets...")
}
```

Now when you write just

```
Foo   // prints `Foo is launching rockets...`
```

this enforces the evaluation of the contents of `Foo`.

So my guess is that in `Predef` this just makes sure that certain things in the `scala` package object and in `List` are initialised. Very unlikely something you would bother as a user.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>The accepted answer has to be wrong.</strike>

Update: The ML provided a couple of helpful links to issues, without saying whether the problem is only [runtime dependencies between modules](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7814) or also [compiler-internal](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/fa63170098) or [similar](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/3262).

Predef is imported at *compile time* to make various definitions available when your source file is compiled.  (Update: but still carries some value definitions, and not all its methods are inlined.  And in any case, even an inlined usage, of `assert` for example, will incur a reference to `Predef$.MODULE$`, because of side-effects at initialization, see below.)

You can turn off that behavior with `-Yno-predef`.  For example,

```
apm@mara:~/goof$ scala -Yno-predef
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.3 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_25).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> "a" -> 1
<console>:8: error: value -> is not a member of String
              "a" -> 1
                  ^
```

<strike>It has nothing to do with runtime evaluation.</strike>  Otherwise, everything in `Predef` and everything it referenced would get loaded before your program got a chance to run.

(Update: yeah, well, guess what.)

In Scala, `import` is not like `#include`.

Useful exercise:

```
scala> :javap -prv scala.Predef$

  private scala.Predef$();
    flags: ACC_PRIVATE
    Code:
      stack=3, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0       
         1: invokespecial #520                // Method scala/LowPriorityImplicits."<init>":()V
         4: aload_0       
         5: putstatic     #522                // Field MODULE$:Lscala/Predef$;
         8: aload_0       
         9: invokestatic  #526                // Method scala/DeprecatedPredef$class.$init$:(Lscala/Predef$;)V
        12: getstatic     #531                // Field scala/package$.MODULE$:Lscala/package$;
        15: pop           
        16: getstatic     #536                // Field scala/collection/immutable/List$.MODULE$:Lscala/collection/immutable/List$;
        19: pop           
        20: aload_0       
        21: getstatic     #540                // Field scala/collection/immutable/Map$.MODULE$:Lscala/collection/immutable/Map$;
        24: putfield      #151                // Field Map:Lscala/collection/immutable/Map$;
        // etc, etc
```

No doubt my understanding is incomplete.